# Sweetalert confirm no espera a la confirmacion para mandar el formulario

Tags: javascript, php, html

Estoy intentando que antes de enviar un formulario pida confirmación con una función estilo confirm con Sweetalert, pero el formulario se envía sin esperar la confirmación.
Esta es la función:

```
function confirmar(){  
    Swal.fire({
        title: '¿Estás seguro?',                
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Si',
        cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar'
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
        document.alquiler.submit();
        }
    })
}
```

Y este es el bloque del formulario:

```
echo "<div id='alquiler'>";
echo "<form name='alquiler' method='POST' action='alquilar.php?codigo=".$juegos[0]["codigo"]."'>
                <select class='dias' name='dias' id='dias' required>
                    <option value=''>Días</option>
                    <option value='1'>1</option>
                    <option value='2'>2</option>
                    <option value='3'>3</option>
                    <option value='4'>4</option>
                    <option value='5'>5</option>
                </select>";
echo "<br><input type='submit' onclick='confirmar()' name='reservar' id='reservar' value='Reservar'></form></div>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso te sucede porque un `<iput type="submit">` siempre va a enviar el formulario al que pertenece cuando le haces click, a no ser que le digas lo contrario.

Una manera de conseguir lo que te propones es cambiándole el tipo a `<input type="button">` ya que quieres ser tú quien controle si el formulario se envía o no. De esta manera tienes un botón limpio, sin comportamiento por defecto.

Otra manera que tienes de hacerlo es usar un `<input type="submit">` y dentro de la función `onclick` prevenir el comportamiento predeterminado del input con `event.preventDefault()`

```
<input type='submit' onclick='confirmar(event)' name='reservar' id='reservar' value='Reservar'>

function confirmar(event) {  
    event.preventDefault();

    Swal.fire({
        title: '¿Estás seguro?',                
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Si',
        cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar'
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
        document.alquiler.submit();
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Ahora si funciona, pero me pasa lo siguiente: en la página del action del formulario, tengo puesto que verifique si se ha pulsado reservar para poder seguir con el proceso con un if(isset($_POST["reservar"])){......}, pero se ve que como cuando llega a esa página lo ultimo que he pulsado es el boton del sweetalert y no el del formulario no sigue con el codigo. ¿Como podría hacer para verificar que se ha enviado el formulario de una manera que funcione?

Comment: Ya no necesitarías validar que se ha pulsado el botón de enviar, puesto que si se ha lanzado el `submit()` es que así ha sido. Aun así, si no quisieras cambiar tu backend podrías añadir al formulario un input hidden: `<input type="hidden" name="enviar" value="enviar">`.

Comment: Creo que lo he solucionado evaluando en el archivo php si existe la variable del select que se pasa por post. Es decir, he puesto if(isset($_POST["dias"])){....} Muchas gracias por la ayuda